# Stochasticity of Fermi problems

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, physics

The great physicist Enrico Fermi was known for his ability to make good
guesses with little or bad data by multiplying series of estimates. [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_problem)

I've seen this described as corresponding to a stochastic process analogous to random diffusion of the square root of the step count on the logarithmic scale.

Do you agree, and if so how would you explain this to a layman?

Comment: Do you have a reference to where you've heard that description?  It may be easier to explain if we had the specifics of that view available.

Comment: I'm afraid that was the totality of detail given. It was noted in passing in an essay on another subject.

Answer (score 1):

Good description here: [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_problem)

If estimate $F$ is a product of $n$ estimates (e.g. the Drake equation for number of possible intelligent civilizations in the universe)

$F=\prod_{i=1}^{n}f_{i}$

then

$\log F = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\log f_{i}$

if each estimate of $\log f$ is approximated as a normal distribution $N(\mu_i,\sigma_i)$ then we have a random-walk stochastic Weiner type process.

The layman can relate to a drunkard's walk ...